# Cannot load custom routes in Phalcon PHP

Tags: php, phalcon

Until yesterday my Phalcon PHP application was running perfectly on PROD and today is working only on DEV and LOCAL environments... and I don't have a clue what is going on there! The codebase is exactly the same on all environments, the configs and the routes are correct as well.

For example, if I want to get to a custom defined route, like "*/my-custom-route*", it always gives me the error message "**MyCustomRouteController handler class cannot be loaded**". But the rest routes are working fine, like "*/contacts*" which comes from **ContactsController**.

As an additional information, "*/my-custom-route*" has been implemented through **ToolsController** and **gearAction()**.

The problem appears only on PROD! On DEV and LOCAL there are no such issues which is super strange... The LIVE server is Debian with Apache. DEV server is the same (Debian/Apache), and LOCAL has Ubuntu/Apache installed. All versions are the latest ones - Phalcon Framework (3.4.5), Apache (2.4.41), PHP7 (7.0.33), MariaDB (10.1.43).

Does anyone have an idea where might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Turns out that it was a configuration issue. I use values from an INI file where *env*, *site_url*, *api_url* are defined and the **site_url** was set without 'www.' which caused the custom URLs to be unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be a case sensitive issue. But since you're running Debian on dev as well don't think this is the issue.
Not sure what changes are done but maybe you're looking at a file being cached by opcache?

Comment: I also don't think it's a case sensitive issue. But regarding your guess about the OPcache, I just tried to call opcache_reset(); in my bootstrap index.php file, and also tried to restart Apache... no result though! I want to thank you for the help, every idea would be something for me while the boss is not calling me on the phone asking "Why some site URLs are not working?" :)